# eBay REST API: invalid_request when exchanging the authorization code for an access token

Tags: rest, ebay-api

I'm trying to connect to the eBay APIs through their new REST API.

I'm using a very simple script to test the flow and I'm using Guzzle.

The guide I'm following is [this](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/rest/ebay-rest/content/oauth-gen-user-token.html).

But when it's time to exchange the authorization code with an access token I ever receive the following response:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"request is invalid","error_uri":null}
```

I really don't know what to try to make this work.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php

...

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $authorization = base64_encode($appId . ':' . $certId);
    $code = urlencode($_GET['code']);
    $body = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=' . $code . '&redirect_uri=' . $ruName;

    $options = [
        \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $authorization,
        ],
        \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::BODY => $body,
        \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::DEBUG => true,
    ];

    try {
        $response = $client->post('https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token', $options);
        die(dump($response->getBody()->__toString(), $response));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        die(dump($e,$_GET, $authorization, $body, $options));
    }
}

// Start the authentication redirecting the user to the eBay's sign-in page
$get_request_token_url = 'https://signin.sandbox.ebay.com/authorize'
    . '?client_id=' . $appId
    . '&redirect_uri=' . $ruName
    . '&response_type=code'
    // Scope for User
    . '&scope=' . urlencode(
        'https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope '.
        'https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.account.readonly '.
        'https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.account '
    );
header('Location: ' . $get_request_token_url);
```

As the documentation is ambigous, I've also tried to set the on-time/temporary `code` returned by eBay directly in the query string (with all the other parameters that should be in the `body`). I've tried also to send them both in the `body` and appending them to the `query_string` but nothing seems to work...

I really don't know what other to try.

Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [The League of Extraordinary Packages OAuth 2.0 Client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client) but patched it a bit for Ebay compatibility:

Ebay Provider class:

```php
namespace Library\Ras\OAuth2\Client\Provider;

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider;

/**
 * Class Ebay
 * @package Library\Ras\OAuth2\Client\Provider
 */
class EbayProvider extends GenericProvider
{

    protected function getAccessTokenOptions(array $params)
    {
        $options = [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization' => sprintf(
                    'Basic %s',
                    base64_encode(sprintf('%s:%s', $params['client_id'], $params['client_secret']))
                ),
            ],
        ];

        unset($params['client_id'], $params['client_secret']);

        if ($this->getAccessTokenMethod() === self::METHOD_POST) {
            $options['body'] = $this->getAccessTokenBody($params);
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```

If you are using Guzzle < 6.0, then custom request factory is needed:

```php
namespace Library\Ras\OAuth2\Tool;

use GuzzleHttp\Message\MessageFactory;
use GuzzleHttp\Message\Request;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Tool\RequestFactory as BaseRequestFactory;

/**
 * Class RequestFactory
 * @package Library\Ras\OAuth2\Tool
 */
class RequestFactory extends BaseRequestFactory
{

    /**
     * Creates a request using a simplified array of options.
     *
     * @param  null|string $method
     * @param  null|string $uri
     * @param  array $options
     *
     * @return Request
     */
    public function getRequestWithOptions($method, $uri, array $options = [])
    {
        $factory = new MessageFactory();
        return $factory->createRequest($method, $uri, $options);
    }
}
```

And finally:

```php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new \Library\Ras\OAuth2\Client\Provider\EbayProvider([
    'clientId' => '<clientId>',
    'clientSecret' => '<clientSecret>',
    'redirectUri' => '<RUName>',
    'urlAuthorize' => 'https://signin.ebay.com/authorize',
    'urlAccessToken' => 'https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token',
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
    'scopeSeparator' => ' ',
    'scopes' => [
        'https =>//api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope',
        'https =>//api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.order.readonly',
        'https =>//api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.order',
    ],
]);

// Only if your Guzzle version is < 6.0
$client->setRequestFactory(new \Library\Ras\OAuth2\Tool\RequestFactory());

if (array_key_exists('code', $_GET)) {
    $applicationToken = $_GET['code'];
    $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
        'code' => $applicationToken,
    ]);
    echo 'User access token: ' . $accessToken;
} else {
    $url = $client->getAuthorizationUrl();
    header('Location: ' . $url);
}
```

Comment: hi , is it working well, can you explain how to generate token

Comment: hi Ololo , can you send the codes. i'm trying to get the token , with the CODE generated , it kepp saying invalid_request

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick , write a new question and link it from here: we will help you...

Comment: @Aerendir ok thank you,i'm using pure php coding, can you debug

Comment: Debug what? I switched to League OAuth. The problem is that is not useful to write all in pure PHP code by yourself. You should use a plugin that supports OAuth. For the moment I've tested the API using League OAuth, but in the past I've used Guzzle with an OAuth2 plugin from Commerceguys, but haven't yet tested it with the eBay API. The eBay documentation is incomplete: the real implementation of the OAuth 2 flow is more complex and is not sufficient to do what they explain in the guide to build the `body` correctly. So, go use a library: you'll save you a lot of time and headhaches!

Comment: thank you much,  i  will try with League OAuth, then if any errors , i post a question with link.

Comment: @Aerendir i have tried with the code discussed in answer, now it redirect to http://signin.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?OAuthAuthorize&error=invalid_request  and it says   "Sorry, we aren't able to complete your request at this time. Please try again later."

Comment: it seems it may be due to the client id and key

Comment: can you test my client auth credentials ?

Comment: to me sandbox test auth is not working from the mip console web site...